# Is NDK native choreographer throttled at 10fps?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I’m developing some C++ Android code and I realized that my animations are happening at only 10fps on an actual low end phone.
Has anyone ever seen Choreographer limit the FPS at such a low number?
Also I am using 32bit color and the default is 16bit.

Comment: Need more information

Comment: No, it was added in API level 24 (Android 7.0).

Comment: Interesting but...

Comment: Don't edit your question into a completely different question. I you have two questions, post them as separate questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hypothetically if the cpu were very slow it might, but this is an octacore so I’m doubting that.